# Finding out if column has only identical values in R for if...else

Tags: r

I'm new to R and have the following problem. I have a big df that looks something like this...

PPC=precipitation

| ID | Area | ppc_1 | ppc_2 | ppc_3 | .... | other_values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PB | 0.989 | 0.787 | 0.676 | .. |  |
| 2 | DR | 0.978 | 0.989 | ..... | .. |  |
| 3 | ... | ... | ... | ... |  |  |

I need to test for normal distribution for every PPC-station per area with the Shapiro-Wilk-Test. To get the necessary data from the weather stations in one column I used the following  "for loop".

My problem is that some weather stations seem to have identical values which causes an error for the Shapiro-Wilk-Test. I tried to circumvent it by using an "If...else- statement", but the "if" clause does not work.

```
#create empty vector to put results in
pvalue_ppc <- as.character()

for (i in 1:length(df$ID)) {
  
  ####filter for ID and PPC                                    
  temp_df<-df  %>%select(starts_with("ppc" 
  ), ID)%>% filter(ID==i )
  
  #melt weather stations over ID 
  temp_df_ID_ppc <- melt(temp_df,
                       id = "ID",
                       value.name = "all_ppc")
  
         #i want to test if all values in df$all_ppc are the same = TRUE
        if(isTRUE(all.equal(temp_df_ID_ppc$all_ppc, countEQ = TRUE))){
               
                        #and if all values are equal, put an "NA" into the vector
                       output <- NA
                      pvalue_ppc[i]<- rbind(output)
         }
        else {
                      output<- shapiro.test(ttemp_df_ID_ppc$all_ppc)
                      #bind results to vector
                      pvalue_ppc[i]<- rbind(output$p.value)
    
  }
}

#bind vector to orig. df
df<- cbind(df, "Pvalue_PPC"=pvalue_ppc)
```

The error I get is

> $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

or it returns TRUE back, even if not all values are equal.

I also tried using "identical(), but it only compared vector to vector

Comment: rather than doing all that just wrap your test with tryCatch so your code will keep running `output <- tryCatch(shapiro.test(ttemp_df_ID_ppc$all_ppc), error = function(e) return(list(p.value = NA)))`

Comment: Since you have decimal numbers, you should not test for equality. See the FAQ: [7.31 Why doesn’t R think these numbers are equal?](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). Try computing the standard deviation using `sd()` and test to see if that is less than a small number, e.g. .001. If so, skip the test.